# 投稿者ごとのカレンダーを表示したい

Tags: wordpress

wordpressで複数人で投稿予定のサイトを作成しております。

それぞれの投稿者のページに `get_calendar` でカレンダーを表示し、投稿のある日にリンクを貼りたいのですが、現状全ての投稿者のリンクが貼られてしまう状況です。

例:
aさん　1日、3日、5日更新　→カレンダーの1、3、5にリンクが貼られて欲しい
bさん　2日、4日、6日更新　→カレンダーの2、4、6にリンクが貼られて欲しい
現状：→カレンダーの1、2、3、4、5、6にリンクが貼られている

カレンダーを表示しているタグは以下です。

```
<?php get_calendar(); ?>
```

お知恵を貸していただけますと助かります。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 勝手ながらタイトルを簡潔にまとめなおしてみました。意に反した内容になっていましたら、お手数ですがご指摘いただくか再度[edit]をお願いします。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます！随分簡潔で分かりやすくなりました。

Comment: こちら自己解決できました！
今後同じような方のためにソースコードを掲載しておきます。

手順：
（1）wp-includes/general-template.phpの中にある、get_calender()関数を、functions.phpにコピー
（2）author idを取得し変数に格納（$uid）
（3）全てのSQL文のWHERE句内に post_author = $uidを挿入

Comment: このサイトでは質問者も回答を投稿できますから、あなたが見つけた解決策を回答として投稿していただけませんか？（質問の編集ではなく）

Comment: @unaristさん
ご指摘ありがとうございます。
回答欄で入れてみました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問を投稿してから48時間経てば解決済みマークも付けられるようになるので、（もしその時まで覚えていたら）こちらもよろしくお願いします。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/8000

Comment: @unaristさん
承知しました！！

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できました！
今後同じような方のためにソースコードを掲載しておきます。

手順：
1.wp-includes/general-template.phpの中にある、get_calender()関数を、functions.phpにコピー
2.author idを取得し変数に格納（$uid）
3.全てのSQL文のWHERE句内に post_author = $uidを挿入

```
//投稿者ごとのリンクをカレンダーに表示
function get_custom_calendar($initial = true, $echo = true) {
    global $wpdb, $m, $monthnum, $year, $wp_locale, $posts, $uid;

    //author IDを取得する
    $uid = get_the_author_meta('id');
    $key = md5( $m . $monthnum . $year );
    if ( $cache = wp_cache_get( 'get_calendar', 'calendar' ) ) {
        if ( is_array($cache) && isset( $cache[ $key ] ) ) {
            if ( $echo ) {
                /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
                echo apply_filters( 'get_calendar', $cache[$key] );
                return;
            } else {
                /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
                return apply_filters( 'get_calendar', $cache[$key] );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( !is_array($cache) )
        $cache = array();

    // Quick check. If we have no posts at all, abort!
    if ( !$posts ) {
        $gotsome = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT 1 as test FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_author = $uid AND post_status = 'publish'　AND post_author = $uid LIMIT 1");
        if ( !$gotsome ) {
            $cache[ $key ] = '';
            wp_cache_set( 'get_calendar', $cache, 'calendar' );
            return;
        }
    }

    if ( isset($_GET['w']) )
        $w = ''.intval($_GET['w']);

    // week_begins = 0 stands for Sunday
    $week_begins = intval(get_option('start_of_week'));

    // Let's figure out when we are
    if ( !empty($monthnum) && !empty($year) ) {
        $thismonth = ''.zeroise(intval($monthnum), 2);
        $thisyear = ''.intval($year);
    } elseif ( !empty($w) ) {
        // We need to get the month from MySQL
        $thisyear = ''.intval(substr($m, 0, 4));
        $d = (($w - 1) * 7) + 6; //it seems MySQL's weeks disagree with PHP's
        $thismonth = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('{$thisyear}0101', INTERVAL $d DAY) ), '%m')");
    } elseif ( !empty($m) ) {
        $thisyear = ''.intval(substr($m, 0, 4));
        if ( strlen($m) < 6 )
                $thismonth = '01';
        else
                $thismonth = ''.zeroise(intval(substr($m, 4, 2)), 2);
    } else {
        $thisyear = gmdate('Y', current_time('timestamp'));
        $thismonth = gmdate('m', current_time('timestamp'));
    }

    $unixmonth = mktime(0, 0 , 0, $thismonth, 1, $thisyear);
    $last_day = date('t', $unixmonth);

    // Get the next and previous month and year with at least one post
    $previous = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_date < '$thisyear-$thismonth-01'
        AND post_type = 'post' AND post_author = $uid AND post_status = 'publish'
            ORDER BY post_date DESC
            LIMIT 1");
    $next = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_date > '$thisyear-$thismonth-{$last_day} 23:59:59'
        AND post_type = 'post' AND post_author = $uid AND post_status = 'publish'
            ORDER BY post_date ASC
            LIMIT 1");

    /* translators: Calendar caption: 1: month name, 2: 4-digit year */
    $calendar_caption = _x('%1$s %2$s', 'calendar caption');
    $calendar_output = '<table id="wp-calendar">
    <caption>' . sprintf($calendar_caption, $wp_locale->get_month($thismonth), date('Y', $unixmonth)) . '</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>';

    $myweek = array();

    for ( $wdcount=0; $wdcount<=6; $wdcount++ ) {
        $myweek[] = $wp_locale->get_weekday(($wdcount+$week_begins)%7);
    }

    foreach ( $myweek as $wd ) {
        $day_name = $initial ? $wp_locale->get_weekday_initial($wd) : $wp_locale->get_weekday_abbrev($wd);
        $wd = esc_attr($wd);
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t<th scope=\"col\" title=\"$wd\">$day_name</th>";
    }

    $calendar_output .= '
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
    <tr>';

    if ( $previous ) {
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="prev"><a href="' . get_month_link($previous->year, $previous->month) . '">« ' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($previous->month)) . '</a></td>';
    } else {
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="prev" class="pad"> </td>';
    }

    $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td class="pad"> </td>';

    if ( $next ) {
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="next"><a href="' . get_month_link($next->year, $next->month) . '">' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($next->month)) . ' »</a></td>';
    } else {
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="next" class="pad"> </td>';
    }

    $calendar_output .= '
    </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
    <tr>';

    $daywithpost = array();

    // Get days with posts
    $dayswithposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT DAYOFMONTH(post_date)
        FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_date >= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-01 00:00:00'
        AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_author = $uid
        AND post_date <= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-{$last_day} 23:59:59'", ARRAY_N);
    if ( $dayswithposts ) {
        foreach ( (array) $dayswithposts as $daywith ) {
            $daywithpost[] = $daywith[0];
        }
    }

    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'camino') !== false || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'safari') !== false)
        $ak_title_separator = "\n";
    else
        $ak_title_separator = ', ';

    $ak_titles_for_day = array();
    $ak_post_titles = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, DAYOFMONTH(post_date) as dom "
        ."FROM $wpdb->posts "
        ."WHERE post_date >= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-01 00:00:00' "
        ."AND post_date <= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-{$last_day} 23:59:59' "
        ."AND post_type = 'post' AND post_author = $uid AND post_status = 'publish'"
    );
    if ( $ak_post_titles ) {
        foreach ( (array) $ak_post_titles as $ak_post_title ) {

                /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
                $post_title = esc_attr( apply_filters( 'the_title', $ak_post_title->post_title, $ak_post_title->ID ) );

                if ( empty($ak_titles_for_day['day_'.$ak_post_title->dom]) )
                    $ak_titles_for_day['day_'.$ak_post_title->dom] = '';
                if ( empty($ak_titles_for_day["$ak_post_title->dom"]) ) // first one
                    $ak_titles_for_day["$ak_post_title->dom"] = $post_title;
                else
                    $ak_titles_for_day["$ak_post_title->dom"] .= $ak_title_separator . $post_title;
        }
    }

    // See how much we should pad in the beginning
    $pad = calendar_week_mod(date('w', $unixmonth)-$week_begins);
    if ( 0 != $pad )
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="'. esc_attr($pad) .'" class="pad"> </td>';

    $daysinmonth = intval(date('t', $unixmonth));
    for ( $day = 1; $day <= $daysinmonth; ++$day ) {
        if ( isset($newrow) && $newrow )
            $calendar_output .= "\n\t</tr>\n\t<tr>\n\t\t";
        $newrow = false;

        if ( $day == gmdate('j', current_time('timestamp')) && $thismonth == gmdate('m', current_time('timestamp')) && $thisyear == gmdate('Y', current_time('timestamp')) )
            $calendar_output .= '<td id="today">';
        else
            $calendar_output .= '<td>';

        if ( in_array($day, $daywithpost) ) // any posts today?
                $calendar_output .= '<a href="' . get_day_link( $thisyear, $thismonth, $day ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $ak_titles_for_day[ $day ] ) . "\">$day</a>";
        else
            $calendar_output .= $day;
        $calendar_output .= '</td>';

        if ( 6 == calendar_week_mod(date('w', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $thismonth, $day, $thisyear))-$week_begins) )
            $newrow = true;
    }

    $pad = 7 - calendar_week_mod(date('w', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $thismonth, $day, $thisyear))-$week_begins);
    if ( $pad != 0 && $pad != 7 )
        $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td class="pad" colspan="'. esc_attr($pad) .'"> </td>';

    $calendar_output .= "\n\t</tr>\n\t</tbody>\n\t</table>";

    $cache[ $key ] = $calendar_output;
    wp_cache_set( 'get_calendar', $cache, 'calendar' );

    if ( $echo ) {
        /**
         * Filter the HTML calendar output.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string $calendar_output HTML output of the calendar.
         */
        echo apply_filters( 'get_calendar', $calendar_output );
    } else {
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
        return apply_filters( 'get_calendar', $calendar_output );
    }
}
```

Comment: `global` は定義済みのグローバル変数を使うために書かれているので、ここでしか使わない `$uid` は含めなくていいかと思います。あと `md5( $m . $monthnum . $year )` をキーとするキャッシュがあるようですが、投稿者ごとに内容が切り替わることは確認されましたか？

Comment: グローバル変数の記述方法についてありがとうございます。

カレンダーのリンクは投稿者ごとになったことを確認済みですが、リンク先の表示でまた問題が。。。

これは本件の内容とは別ですのでもう少し粘って分からなければ、またこちらを利用したいと思います。